# iOS: setting buttons pressed state

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to find the best approach to doing this.  I have 5 custom buttons on a view controller and I am trying to have the button stay highlighted if it is clicked.  I know how to do this but I am trying to only allow 1 button to be highlighted at a time.  So if a user clicks a button and highlights it, but clicks another, then the most recent button clicked will stay highlighted and the previous will unhighlight.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You need algo or full code?

Comment: Store the current button in a property and unselect it when selecting the new one?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to alter the behavior of a button **in Xcode.** It's certainly possible to do so **in your iOS app,** though.

Comment: @H2CO3 : in your edit, you added **iOS** to the title. I think it's a bad practice to include tags in the title (I read that on a meta.SO thread). I don't mean to teach you anything (c'mon, you have 53.1k rep and I don't even have 2k, lol) but I'm pretty sure it's better to remove all tags from title. What do you think ?

Comment: @rdurand 1. Then why did you have "Xcode" in the title originally? (It's not only a tag, it's even inappropriate.) 2. That's for giving context. "setting buttons pressed state" is not too informative - practically every GUI library and OS out there does have buttons, and you don't want a Windows QT programmer to come here and spread the wisdom when you're looking for an iOS/Objective-C solution.

Comment: @H2CO3 : 1. I agree, having Xcode in the title is inappropriate, and 2. aren't tags here for that ? I don't want to start an off-topic discussion so let's leave it at that, but from what I read on meta, it seems to be good-practice to remove tags from titles, so maybe we should have a look into that.. It's just that I see you a lot on the iOS topics, and was surprised that your edit was "conflicting" with what I read :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep a reference to all your buttons (for example, if you use IB, have links in your code like `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;` for all your buttons).

Then link all your buttons to the same method for a press on the button. I'll call it `buttonPressed`.

Impement it like this :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buttonPressed = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:_button1, _button2, _button3, nil];
    bool buttonIsHighlighted = NO;

    // Check if a button is already highlighted
    for (UIButton *button in buttons) {

        if (button.highlighted) {

            buttonIsHighlighted = YES;
        }
    }

    // If a button is highlighted, un-highlight all except the one pressed
    // If no button is highlighted, just highlight the right one
    if (buttonIsHighlighted) {

        for (UIButton *button in buttons) {

            if (buttonPressed == button) {

                buttonIsHighlighted = YES;

            } else {

                button.highlighted = NO;
            }
        }

    } else {

        buttonPressed.highlighted = YES;
    }
}
```

I can't test this code but I'm pretty sure it should work. Let me know if something's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Put your buttons in an `NSArray` and when user clicks on a button check if another is highlighted. If `YES`, unhighlight it and highlight the one was pressed. If `NO`, highlight directly the one pressed.

Solution 2:
You can save the highlighted button in a global variable declared in `@interface` or in a `@property`. When users click the new one unhighlight the previous.

Comment: Well, looks like your solution 1 is pretty much what I suggested, lol. I don't really catch the second one though ?